# Generating JPG's from office files (.doc .ppt etc) using PHP

Tags: php, ms-office, jpeg

I'm building an application where people can upload files and share them with other people. Part of what we are looking to do is allow people to preview the file on-line.

Is there a strait forward way to generate a jpgs for the first X amount of pages from a document? We could then place these jpgs in the web page allowing the user to preview.

I have looked at installing open office on the server but was hoping there was a php library somewhere that does the same job.

Can anybody help?

Cheers

---

Btw, doesnt have to be jpg, any image file would be fine (actually even pdf would be ok)

Comment: I think it is impossible without having any mean that converts them into text or PHP extension! If there any way I will be happy to hear about it.

Comment: Hi Matt, no it doesnt have to be JPG... any image file would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Try this with com class:

You can use com class for convert office file to jpg

COM class Reference: -

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

or below code is convert ppt to jpg format

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ShotDev.Com Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
    $ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");
    $ppApp->Visible = True;

    $strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); // C:/AppServ/www/myphp

    $ppName = "MySlides.ppt";
    $FileName = "MyPP";

    //*** Open Document ***//
    $ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));

    //*** Save Document ***//
    $ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs($strPath."/".$FileName,17);  //'*** 18=PNG, 19=BMP **'
    //$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs(realpath($FileName),17);

    $ppApp->Quit;
    $ppApp = null;
?>
PowerPoint Created to Folder <b><?=$FileName?></b>
</body>
</html>

---------------------------

Or try this :-

$powerpnt = new COM("powerpoint.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Powerpoint");

$presentation = $powerpnt->Presentations->Open(realpath($file), false, false, false) or die("Unable to open presentation");

foreach($presentation->Slides as $slide)

{

    $slideName = "Slide_" . $slide->SlideNumber;

    $exportFolder = realpath($uploadsFolder);

    $slide->Export($exportFolder."\\".$slideName.".jpg", "jpg", "600", "400");

}

$powerpnt->quit();
```

?>

or convert word to jpg

```
<?php
// starting word
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word");
echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}\n";

//bring it to front
$word->Visible = 1;

//open an empty document
$word->Documents->Add();

//do some weird stuff
$word->Selection->TypeText("This is a test...");
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("Useless test.doc");

//closing word
$word->Quit();

//free the object
$word = null;
?>
```

Comment: If this solution succeeded, It will need Windows based Server!

Comment: I think it will working all servers read this http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Comment: Hi,.. could you explain how this works to me? I was under the impression that the com class loaded a 3rd party application on the server? Have I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: @Abid Hussain I don't thik that it all, as I remeber, COM is restricted only for Windows. You will find Com class is categorized under Windows Only Extensions. Look at http://us2.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.windows.php

Comment: sorry not all only it will working only window server read this us2.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php

Comment: Unbelievable that no one has voted this answer up. Tested the code on windows machine(obviously) and both options worked like a charm. Well done Abid! PS: For anyone reading you're going to need powerpoint installed on the machine also.

Comment: I don't see how the word sample would produce a JPG.

Comment: convert word to jpg is not working. it creates new doc file but not jpg.any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Office Interop to automate such a task, see Microsoft reasons for that here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

The best approach is to use a powerful library such as Aspose.Slides (compatibility with ppt, pptx, powerful manipulation) that are designed to be used as an API.

You can consume Aspose.Slides from PHP by means of the NetPhp library. There is an example here:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/powerpoint-presentation-images-php-drupal-example

The relevant piece of code is this one, it has some Drupal specific stuff, but you can see how it goes and make it work on other places:

```
protected function processFilePowerpoint(array $file, array &$files) {
    /** @var \Drupal\wincachedrupal\NetPhp */
    $netphp = \Drupal::service('netphp');

    $runtime = $netphp->getRuntime();

    $runtime->RegisterAssemblyFromFile("libraries/_bin/aspose/Aspose.Slides.dll", "Aspose.Slides");
    $runtime->RegisterAssemblyFromFullQualifiedName("System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", "System.Drawing");

    $destination = strtr(PresentacionSlide::UPLOAD_LOCATION, ['[envivo_presentacion:id]' => $this->entity->id()]);
    file_prepare_directory($destination, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);

    $sourcefile = drupal_realpath($file['tmppath']);

    $presentation = $runtime->TypeFromName("Aspose.Slides.Presentation")->Instantiate($sourcefile);
    $format = $runtime->TypeFromName("System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat")->Png;

    $x = 0;

    /** @var \NetPhp\Core\NetProxyCollection */
    $slides = $presentation->Slides->AsIterator();

    foreach ($slides as $slide) {
      $x++;
      $bitmap = $slide->GetThumbnail(1, 1);
      $destinationfile = $destination . "\\slide_{$x}.png";
      $bitmap->Save(drupal_realpath($destinationfile), $format);
      $files[] = PresentacionSlide::fromFile($destinationfile);
    }

    $presentation->Dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

For a PHP-specific option you could use [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) - this library is written in PHP and provides classes to read from and write to different document file formats (including `.doc` and `.docx`), but it won't give you the ability to convert from the full range of Office files.

To convert any Office file on any platform you could use a file conversion API like [Zamzar](https://developers.zamzar.com). It can convert from all Office formats (DOC / DOCX / PPT / PPTX / XLS / XLSX) into images (JPG, PNG, GIF etc) and PDF.

Code to call from PHP would be as follows (more info [in the docs](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Start_a_conversion_job)).

```
<?php
// Build request
$endpoint = "https://api.zamzar.com/v1/jobs";
$apiKey = "YOUR_KEY";
$sourceFilePath = "/tmp/my.doc"; // Or DOCX/PPT/PPTX/XLS/XLSX
$targetFormat = "jpg";

$sourceFile = curl_file_create($sourceFilePath);    
$postData = array(
  "source_file" => $sourceFile,
  "target_format" => $targetFormat
);

// Send request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":");
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Process response (with link to converted files)
$response = json_decode($body, true);
print_r($response);
?>
```